# Component undefined in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm playing around with ReactJS. I have defined three components, which are nested:

**UserProfile.jsx**

```
var React = require('react');

var UserProfile = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      username: "zuck"
    };
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <UserProfile>
        <ProfileImage username={this.props.username}/>
        <ProfileLink username={this.props.username}/>
      </UserProfile>
    );
  }

});
React.render(<UserProfile username="zuck"/>, document.body);

module.exports = UserProfile;
```

**ProfileLink.jsx**

```
var React = require('react');

var ProfileLink = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    return (
      <a href="//facebook.com/{this.props.username}">{this.props.username}</a>
    );
  }

});

module.exports = ProfileLink;
```

**ProfileImage.jsx**

```
var React = require('react');

var ProfileImage = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    return (
      <img src="//graph.facebook.com/{this.props.username}/picture"/>
    );
  }

});

module.exports = ProfileImage;
```

My html file basically only includes the three jsx files (btw, is there a way to bundle all these into a single request during development?)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>React FB Link</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="UserProfile.jsx"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="ProfileLink.jsx"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="ProfileImage.jsx"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using beefy to handle and serve the JSX files, using `beefy *.jsx 8000 -- -t reactify`.

The resulting files are (in truncated form):

- [UserProfile.jsx](http://pastebin.com/xcsX02z7)
- [ProfileLink.jsx](http://pastebin.com/gDL8Z8Gi)
- [ProfileImage.jsx](http://pastebin.com/k2xDZy56)

Loading the html page results in an error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: ProfileImage is not defined
>   with reference to line 15 in `UserProfile.jsx`:

```
React.createElement(ProfileImage, {username: this.props.username}),
```

Comment: I would use a bundler and then use ```var ProfileImage = require('ProfileImage')```.

Answer (score 3):

You might need to load `ProfileImage.jsx` and `ProfileLink.jsx` before your `UserProfile.jsx` since right now the page is parsing `Userprofile.jsx` first and it doesn't know what `ProfileImage` mean (because you haven't loaded it yet)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>React FB Link</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="ProfileLink.jsx"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="ProfileImage.jsx"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="UserProfile.jsx"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can use any module bundler to bundle up your files ([Browserify](http://browserify.org/), [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/), [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/)) into one single file as entry point